# Difference between RequestContext and MessageContext in JAX WS

Tags: soap, jax-ws

What is the difference between RequestContext and MessageContext in JAX-WS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MessageContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/ws/handler/MessageContext.html) provides access to the current inbound or outbound message in a JAX-WS call, specifically for JAX-WS handlers.  Inbound to a service provider is the request message while outbound is the response; For a JAX-WS client handler, outbound is the request and inbound is the response.

I had to look up [RequestContext](https://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/jax-ws-20-fcs/arch/com/sun/xml/ws/client/RequestContext.html) - it isn't technically a JAX-WS class.  It's a proprietary (read: implementation) class in the JAX-WS reference implementation.  I don't think you'd want to couple/compile your code against this, but I do expect you'd see it during debugger sessions if you're using the JAX-WS RI.

If by chance you're referring to [BindingProvider.getRequestContext()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/ws/BindingProvider.html#getRequestContext()), this is a `Map<String, Object>` that is a map that contains values for initializing the outbound request message for a JAX-WS client.  For example, to programmatically set the endpoint URL:

```
Map<String, Object> requestContext = ((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext();
requestContext.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, myCustomEndpointUrl);
```